# Problem with OutSequence after using <call>

Tags: wso2, esb

I'm building a proxy that receives a Base64 stream, saves it to disk and then reads it back to send it as binary to an URL endpoint. Then it has to respond back to the initial message processing the URL endpoint's response.

The resumed proxy looks like this:

```
<inSequence>
        [...]
     <payloadFactory>
        [...]
     </payloadFactory>
        [...]
     <call>
        <endpoint>
           <address uri="vfs:file:///somewhere"/>
        </endpoint>
     </call>
     <fileconnector.read>
        <source>/somewhere</source>
        <contentType>application/pdf</contentType>
     </fileconnector.read>
        [...]  
     <send>   
        <endpoint>
           <http method="POST"
                 uri-template="someURL"/>
        </endpoint>
     </send>
  </inSequence>
  <outSequence>
     <payloadFactory>
        [...]
     </payloadFactory>
     <send/>
  </outSequence>
```

Everithing works fine but the response from the URL is never processed and the OutSequence never reached (I've set up logs inside to trace it).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Fixed it placing a _loopback_ here: </send><loopback/></inSequence>

Comment: But you are getting a response back? (try to enable configure->logging->ynapse.transport.http.wire)

Comment: No... I was getting a response but it was from the first message. I ended up not making the first call and storing the file on disk using a java connector.